# Get property from objects to convert to simple array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5e235b42a21b160a40c4a82f",
    "title": "category one"
  },
  {
    "id": "5e235b3ea21b160a40c4a82e",
    "title": "category two"
  }
]
```

And I want to convert it to the following array:

```
[
  "5e235b42a21b160a40c4a82f",
  "5e235b3ea21b160a40c4a82e"
]
```

Anyone have a simple suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by iterating over the Object values and taking each `id` value.

The simplest way of doing this is by using `.map()` like so:

```
const newArray = myArray.map(item => item.id);
```

This should take each item and form the `id` property into an array.